# haskell: reader-monad for dependency-injection

Tags: haskell, dependency-injection

i get the basic functionality of the reader-monad from learnyouahaskell book and i've seen some advises here to make use of it for dependency-injection.
even there are some examples here on stackoverflow, i dont know how to use it for integration-testing.

my code is:

```
list :: Ctx -> [String] -> IO String
list ctx args = do
    d <- eitherDecode <$> Uplink.get (token ctx) (endpointActivities ctx) :: IO (Either String Activities)
    case d of 
        Left err -> return err 
        Right result -> return $ unlines . filterByPrefix (parsePrefix args) . extractNames $ activities result
```

uplink.hs

```
get :: String -> String -> IO B.ByteString
get token endpoint = do
    req <- parseRequest endpoint
    resp <- httpLBS $ withAuth token req
    return $ getResponseBody resp
```

how can i mock the **httpLBS** - call for integration-testing with the reader-monad?

---

**EDIT: !!!!**

i almost have it now with the reader-monad. the only problem left is that i dont know how i can define that httpsLBS-function in my Ctx-data-type.

**httpLBS**-function-signature:

```
httpLBS :: MonadIO m => Request -> m (Response ByteString)
```

my Ctx data-type-definition:

```
data Ctx =
    Ctx {
        token :: String,
        endpointActivities :: String,
        endpointTimeTrackingStart :: String,
        httpLBSFunc :: MonadIO m => Request -> m (Response ByteString)
    } deriving (Show)
```

i always get the error: *Not in scope: type variable ‘m’*
how can i define that function in my Ctx-data-type with its constraints?

i promise, that i will post my solution afterwards, when this last problem is solved

Comment: I'm not sure I know what dependency injection really is, but why not parameterize `get` by the http client function, like: `get myHttpLBS token endpoint = do ...`. `Reader` is an abstraction around argument passing. I don't tend to reach for it unless both of: 1) I already have a monad stack, and 2) I have multiple top-level functions that call each other, and in particular I'd like to pass some value _through_ a function, i.e. there is some function that does nothing but pass an argument to some other function. Other folks probably feel differently

Comment: In functional programming, [you can't use dependency injection because it makes everything impure](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/01/27/from-dependency-injection-to-dependency-rejection). Instead, you compose functions, keeping as many of them pure as possible.

Comment: Did you write `uplink.hs`? Don't hard-code `httpLBS`; make it a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell, dependency injection is just higher order programming + currying. You can write your code as the following.

```
-- where (? -> ?) is the type of httpLBS
get_ :: (? -> ?) -> String -> String -> IO B.ByteString
get_ httpFunc token endpoint = do
    req <- parseRequest endpoint
    resp <- httpFunc $ withAuth token req
    return $ getResponseBody resp

getProduction = get_ httpLBS

getTest = get_ httpMock
```